# If one row is affected by a condition how can i cascade it to select all rows with that identifier?

Tags: sql, oracle

If one row is affected by a condition how can i cascade it to select all rows with that identifier?

I'm using MINUS to compare two tables.

One row is being put into an exceptions file I would like all of the affected rows that have the same identifier to also feature in that exceptions file.

— example —

Rowid1    Date1

Rowid1    Date2

Rowid1    Date3

Rowid2    Date4

Rowid2    Date5

Now if a date falls after a certain date criteria say “2019-07-01” then I want to get all rows that have the same rowid to be put in an exceptions file.

Comment: Could you please add a simple example?

Comment: Added an example. Please ask for more information if you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have much informations there but are you looking for something like this ?

```
SELECT * FROM AnyTable 
WHERE common_id IN 
( 
SELECT common_id
FROM ExceptionTable
WHERE Field = 'Foo' -- I don't know if that where clause is necessary
)
```

You can use `=` operator instead of `IN` if you are sure that only 1 row is returned.

Comment: I think it’s going to be something similar to this. Thank you